# camel - how to receive metrics data for counter

Tags: spring, apache-camel, counter, metrics

I want a predicate that checks if the counter reached a specific value. Is it possible to get the value from the metrics counter?

```
from("file:/some/file/to/check.txt").id("read-file")
    .split()
    .tokenize("\n")
    .streaming()
    .parallelProcessing()
    .to("metrics:counter:simple.counter")
    .to("direct:test");

from("direct:test").id("do-something")
    . // do something
    .aggregate(constant(true), aggregationStrategy)
    .completionPredicate(counterPredicate)
    . // do something after finished all lines
    .to("direct:end");
```

I need some help with the **counterPredicate**.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use an AtomicInteger, put it in camel context to access and increment it. Use MVEL to form the completion predicate.

The predicate shall look something like :

```
mvel("this.context.property.counter == this.context.property.DESIRED_VALUE")
```

Answer (score 1):

camel-metrics endpoint doesn't support create a consumer, I'm afraid you need to access the MetricsRegistry yourself in your counterPredicate.

```
MetricRegistryService registryService = camelContext.hasService(MetricsRegistryService.class);
if (registryService != null) {
    MetricsRegistry registry = registryService.getMetricsRegistry();
    ...
 }
```